# Can't parse shortcode inside an acf field (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, parsing, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I need to parse a shortcode [ajaxdomainchecker].
I took action as below but it doesn't parse the shortcode, just shows a shortcode text.
(I tried the shortcode out of the acf field, it parses the shortcode.
$myvalue = get_field( "field_60f5d9a277654" ); echo do_shortcode($myvalue); 
The problem: it doesn't directly parses the shortcode in an acf field.
The parsed code displays where the php code located.)

Would you please let me know how to parse the shortcode?

1. Added a shortcode [ajaxdomainchecker] into Wysiwyg Editor field:
   [image]

2. Added the following code in a single post page, but shows a shortcode text:

```
$post = get_post();
echo do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'testsc', $single = true));
```

3. Added the following code in a functions.php, but shows a shortcode text:

```
function my_acf_format_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    return do_shortcode( $value );
}
add_filter('acf/format_value/key=field_90f5c9a536352', 'my_acf_format_value', 10, 3);
```

[image]


Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `echo do_shortcode('[ajaxdomainchecker]')` in a regular file? like `front-page.php`, could be that this shortcode doesn't even exist and thats why it returns the shortcode text

Comment: Hi: Thank you for your comment. I tried it out of the acf field and it loads the shortcode. It just doesn't load in the acf field...

Comment: How is your textarea is set? you most likely have it as `p` or `br` for every new line, instead try to set it to `no format` or use plain text field

Comment: Hi Buttered: Oh.. I looked into the acf field, but I couldn't find no fromat function. Should I set tabs to text only, then it will be no format? Would you please let me know how to set?

Comment: The formating for textarea is located in `new lines`, i could add a image if you want. if you still can't find it, try replacing `textarea` field into `text`

Comment: Ah.. I added the shortcode to Wysiwyg, so I couldn't find it. And, I added it to a textarea with no format, but still shows the text...

Comment: make sure you dont have any spaces or unusual characters, dont copy pase the shortcode text, write it manualy so you know for sure the `[` `]` are correct and not unicodes

Comment: Ah.. I actually copy and pasted. Yep, I wrote the shortcode (checked the mistypo), textarea with no format, and texted above both codes but still it shows a text... I was wondering if there is any other code that I can try?

Answer (score 0):

1. WYSIWYG editor is the wrong choice for ACF field, change it to a Text field instead.
2. Why use `get_post_meta()` when ACF comes with `get_field()`?

**Try:**

```
$my_shortcode = get_field('testsc');
if ($my_shortcode) {  
  $my_shortcode_content = do_shortcode($my_shortcode);
  if ($my_shortcode_content) {
    echo $my_shortcode_content);
  } else {
    echo 'Shortcode found, but is empty';
  }
} else {
  echo 'Unavailable';
}
```

if needed, you can add the post id as a second parameter to `get_field()`:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: Hi Hillel: Thank you for your help. Would you please let me know where do I have to add the code? In a functions.php? Or in a single post page?

Comment: I added your code in a single post page, and the page shows nothing... I tried $myvalue = get_field( "field_60f5d9a279544" ); echo do_shortcode($myvalue); it loads the shortcode, but the problem is that it doesn't parse the code inside the text field. It displays the shortcode where I put the php code.... I need to parse the shorcode inside the acf field...

Comment: For your first question, in a single post page TEMPLATE file (such as single.php in your themes directory). As for the second comment, don't use the field id with get_field(), use the field_name. (I suggest you'll head to the ACF website they have great documentation there, with code examples you can use)

Comment: Hi Hillel: Thank you for your comment. I tried it in my single post template but the entire page shows nothing. I read ACF's comments and it says Wysiwyg can only parses the shortcode. So I also tried it but still it doesn't parse... Thank you anyway : )